# Comparação de string python dentro do if

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

Minha comparação de strings relativamente simples não dá certo e não encontro o motivo.

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

import csv
import os

def sortKeywords():
    keyw = []
    sheetsList = os.listdir('.')
    for sheet in sheetsList:
        if ((os.path.isfile(sheet))and(sheet.endswith(".csv"))):
            file = open(sheet)
            lines = csv.reader(file)
            for line in lines:
                if(line[1] != "Keyword")
                    print(line[1])

sortKeywords()
```

O seguinte erro aparece:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O problema é que você não colocou os dois pontos ( `:` ) para iniciar o bloco de código da condicional.

Answer (score 1):

Em Pythos, os "if statements" e os ciclos acabam sempre com `:`

Por isso, basta apenas mudar:

```
if(line[1] != "Keyword")
```

por

```
if line[1] != "Keyword":
```

Comment: Achava que estava respondendo no geral, foi engano!

Answer (score 1):

Como alguns já comentaram o que deve ser modificado é o dois pontos no final da declaração da linha 14, conforme apontado na imagem:

```
if line[1] != "Keyword":
```

**Além de simplesmente fazer a alteração, é importante entender a mensagem de erro que foi retornada**

Toda vez que é retornado um `SyntaxError` significa que houve algum problema no momento do interpretador Python entender o que foi escrito. Assim como acontece em uma língua, como português, temos nossas próprias regras de sintaxe que se referem a maneira que o idioma é escrito. Com o Python e com qualquer outra linguagem de programação isso não é diferente.

No momento que você executa o arquivo Python, por baixo dos panos é realizado uma compreensão do que foi escrito (etapa que chamamos de parser). Se não for reconhecida essa estrutura ([comparando com as regras da linguagem já predeterminadas](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/grammar.html)), um erro de sintaxe é estourado, daí o `SyntaxError`. Inclusive ele facilita apontando a linha que ocorreu.

Referência do erro de Sintaxe: https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#SyntaxError

É sempre bom tentar identificar esses tipos de erros que são retornados. Fazendo uma busca pelo tipo de erro na documentação fica mais fácil de entender o cenário :)